# Why aren't $\infty$-groupoids commutative in HoTT?

Tags: type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

I'm trying to read through HoTT, but I'm confused by the path induction principle, it seems too strong at the first glance. I tried "proving" that all suitable paths commute, and it looks like I kind of managed to do it. Where did I make a mistake?

Given a type $A$ with a judgmentally unique term $a: A$ (for any $x: A$ we assert $x \equiv a$), we want to prove that for any $p, q: a =_A a$ we can construct an equality $p \cdot q = q \cdot p$ (I'm using \cdot here because the book's typesetting uses a macro that I don't want to copy-paste).

So we want to construct: $\mathsf{comm}:\prod_{x:A}\prod_{p,q:x=_{A}x}p\cdot q=q\cdot p$.

Define $C(x,p):\equiv\prod_{q:a=_{A}x}p\cdot q=q\cdot p$ (type checks: the concatenation is well-defined because $(a=_{A}x)\equiv(a=_{A}a)$, and the function that defines the induction base should have the type $\prod_{q:a=_{A}x}\mathsf{refl}_{a}\cdot q=q\cdot\mathsf{refl}_{x}$. We construct this function by trivially combining witnesses to the absorption of unity law for $\infty$-groupoids (and the witness for the symmetry of equality).

I'm not sure but I think we can relax the judgmental uniqueness condition by induction over subtypes of the form $\sum_{x: A} x =_A a$ for a fixed $a: A$ and then using the witness to equality in place of the judgmental uniqueness.

I know that I must have made a mistake somewhere because clearly people haven't spent more than a decade developing this theory without noticing this issue, but I just don't know how to find an error short of learning Coq. Please help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This proof does indeed work for a type with a judgmentally unique term. This type is the contractible type, so all of its identity types are contractible as well. In particular, $p \cdot q = q \cdot p$ holds trivially for that type. The type $\sum_{x : A} x =_A a$ is also contractible, so it holds there too. More generally, any set has propositional identity types, so any two terms of an identity type are equal if they exist.

However, the proof as written doesn't really generalize at all. The key thing is that path induction *requires* that the endpoint be "free", and in particular independent of the start point. What that means is that path induction doesn't really work on terms of the form $p : x = x$, which is what you'd need in order to define the type $p \cdot q = q \cdot p$.

In your proof, you took advantage of the fact that $x \equiv a$ to sort of cheat and have the endpoint both free (an arbitrary term of type $A$ independent of $a$) and fixed (judgmentally equal to $a$) in order to define $p \cdot q = q \cdot p$. The right and left sides of this equality a priori have different types, but just happen to be judgmentally the same.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a checklist for avoiding this kind of errors when using HoTT informally?

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko The key thing with path induction is that the hypothesis is of the form $\prod_{x : A} \prod_{p: a = x} P(x, p)$. As I said, your proof is correct, but it relies on $x \equiv a$ and that's why it doesn't generalize.